# HighStock - Issue with dynamic charts when navigator is disabled

Tags: dynamic, highcharts, navigator

I am using the dynamic chart of Highstock. I happen to disable the navigator control of the chart, but have the scrollbar enabled. Now the issue is - if I zoom the chart once, the lines that are already drawn for the curves start to get deleted/erased starting from the left side of the chart and after a certain amount of time all the lines of each curve on the chart get deleted. But if I enable navigator control for the chart, this issue is not see.

Comment: Please replicate your example as live demo.

Comment: Yes please give us a fiddle. It's very likely that you're setting something to null and highcharts responds by acting weird. It's the default response to that kind of action.